Equivalent conditions for orthogonality of polynomials (OPS) with respect to a linear functional
Below is theorem $2.1$ from Chihara's 'An Introduction to Orthogonal Polynomials'

Let $ \mathcal{L} $ be a moment functional, and let $ \{P_n(x)\} $ be a sequence of polynomials. Then the following are equivalent:
$ (a) \{P_n(x)\} $ is an orthogonal polynomial system (OPS) with respect to $ \mathcal{L} $; 
$ (b)  \mathcal{L}[\pi(x) P_n(x)] = 0 $ for every polynomial $ \pi(x) $ of degree $ m < n $, while $ \mathcal{L}[\pi(x) P_n(x)] \neq 0 $ if $ m = n $; 
$ (c) \mathcal{L}[x^m P_n(x)] = K_n \delta_{mn} $, where $ K_n \neq 0 $, for $ m = 0, 1, \dots, n $

I am stuck with the $c \implies a$ part of the proof. I have shown that $L(P_n(x)P_m(x))=\Lambda_n\delta_{m,n}$ for some non zero scalar $\Lambda$. But I have assumed the first condition of an OPS which says that each $P_n$ has degree $n$.
Chihara simply claims "$b\implies c \implies a$ is trivial"
I am unable to shiw that each $P_n$ has degree $n$
